# C# formato de un celda en excel

Tags: c#, excel, numberformat

Necesito abrir un archivo de excel **xlsx** quitarle las comas a un par de celas para que pueda convertir el archivo en **.csv**. Quisero saber si puedo hacer esto con un **NumberFormat** o algo similar? Estoy empezando de la row 15, por es en donde empieza a desplegarse la información

Hasta este punto logro cambiar los formatos de las celdas , pero no logro hacer que se queden en la hoja de excel. Esto es lo que tengo:

```js
Application excel = new Application();
Workbook sheet = excel.Workbooks.Open(filePatht);
Worksheet x = excel.ActiveSheet as Worksheet;
_Worksheet xlWorksheet = sheet.Sheets[1];
Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;

for (int ix = 15; ix < rowCount; ix++) {
     var x18 = xlRange.Cells[ix, 8].Text;
     var x19 = xlRange.Cells[ix, 9].Text;
      xlRange.Cells[ix, 8].NumberFormat = "0.00";
      xlRange.Cells[ix, 9].NumberFormat = "0.00";
}

sheet.Close(true);
excel.Quit();
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(x);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sheet);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Asegúrate que  xlRange[ix, 8] y xlRange[ix, 9] hacen menciones a las celdas donde quieres actuar. en la línea `xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange` asignas `xlRange` al rango en uso de la hoja (1). No sé en C#, pero en VBA, si quisiera entonces actuar con las celdas (15,8) y (15,9) **dentro de ese rango**, tendría que ser `xlRange.Cells(ix, 8).Replace(",", "",)`. No sé si te puede servir de ayuda para tu problema. Dices que tu código no da error, pero no hace lo que quieres, así que quizás está llamando a otras celdas diferentes a las que quieres llamar en realidad.

Comment: @ElierSánchezE-Infante pues ya agregué lo que me sugieres y no hay error, pero no hace lo que quiero y ya verifiqué que las celdas que quiero son la 8 y 9

Comment: Comprueba si el Excel tiene algún tipo de formato de celdas en esas celdas. Si tienen formato, tu ves la coma pero en la celda no hay, deberas modificar el formato

Comment: @Juanjo pues si esta ocupado un formato con comas, yo sé que podría quitarle el formato y evitarme todo el problema, pero debo hacerlo de esta manera.

Comment: Otra opción sería asegurarse que el carácter que quieres reemplazar es una coma. ¿tienes acceso al archivo que quieres modificar? ¿Puedes colgar aquí un pantallazo o un ejemplo de los datos y así nos hacemos una idea?

Comment: Correcto, pero si lo que tienes el numero 1234 y tu ves 12,34, en la celda tienes 1234 por lo que el replace no te va a funcionar nunca. Tienes que cambiar el formato de la celda. En estos enlaces dicen como hacerlo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401996/microsoft-interop-excel-formatting-cells y en este https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.numberformat.aspx

Comment: @Juanjo agregué esto a mi for ** xlRange.NumberFormat = "0.00" **pero las comas persisten

Comment: No falta un save en algun lado?

Comment: Efectivamente, es como @Juanjo dice. Si el formato de la celda está puesto para que enseñe una coma como separador de miles o decimal, el método `Replace` no va a funcionar, porque aunque visualmente veas la coma, en realidad no forma parte del valor, y por lo tanto, `Replace` no tiene efecto porque no existe esa coma. Prueba con `NumberFormat = "0"`

Comment: Efectivamente hacía falta un save() agradezco a todos por su atención. Si alguien quiere escribir una respuesta para que la de como respuesta correcta, siéntase libre al respecto yo con todo gusto les doy la respuesta :3

Comment: El mérito es de @Juanjo, que apostó desde el principio por la opción del Formato, así que escriba él la respuesta, que la votaremos ^^

Comment: hahahahhahahaha el que lo postee primero ;D , yo sé que en esta red la mayoría son unos caballeros y gente decente, por otra lado creo en la democracia y en la competencia, así que ahí deciden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que la celda tiene un formato por lo que tu ves un valor con formato (comas, puntos, simbolos de monedas) pero el valor que tienes que tratar no tiene formato, por lo que no se puede usar la funcion replace.
Primero tienes que quitarle el formato a la celda o celdas, con NumberFormat = "0", guardar el documento y ya tratar el valor que tienes que tu quieres.

Personalmente, los puntos me dan igual, me alegra mas contribuir a solucionar un problema, sobre todo cuando uno esta atascado y no sabe donde mirar.
Saludos

Comment: Muy bien visto lo del formato. Parece una tontería, pero más de una vez los formatos son unos quebraderos de cabeza enormes. Afortunadamente, suelen ser fáciles de solucionar :)